# Get name of QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt

Is there any way to get the name of a `QPushButton`?

i.e.

```
self.pushButton_9_3.setObjectName("pushButton_9_3")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you have a reference to the button you can simply use

```
my_button.objectName()
```

or in your case

```
self.pushButton_9_3.objectName()
```

Comment: its not working in my program can you please tell me is there any method to get the name of the pushbutton